# Bootstrap datepicker showing today's date from local browser

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timezone, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker which can be found [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Now it has one parameter to highlight today's date

```
todayHighlight: true
```

which can be used like these

```
$('#date').datepicker({
todayHighlight: true
```

Now the proble is that my application is for pst timezone. So when i am opening in indian it is higlighting today's date according to ist means indian time.

so how can i make it showing pst present date.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the date using setUTCDate --> [Documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#setutcdate)